# Interpreting ANCOVA results

Tags: ancova

independent variable gender. Gender is a binary column consisting of 0 and 1.From the linear model summary below my observations are:

1. Gender is significant for height dependent variable. Which means height and weight's relationship for males and females are different.
2. Weight is significant as well which means weight influences height.

I am not sure about my first assumption. Would you say my statement is right and gender significance shows that for males and females weight and height relationship are different? Or would you say just being male and female effects height and it's significance does not show anything about the relationship between weight and height?

````r
Call:
lm(formula = height ~ weight + as.factor(gender), data = example.data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-26.8555  -6.0428   0.0415   6.0871  26.5539 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -9.76841    1.87468  -5.211 2.19e-07 ***
weight             0.49532    0.02278  21.741  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(gender)0 3.09201    0.48129   6.424 1.86e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.526 on 1293 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2705,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2694 
F-statistic: 239.7 on 2 and 1293 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```
````

Comment: If you are examing a particular place where the population is essentially genetically homogeneous, then Male/Female difference should be more significant than from measuring in a more heterogeneous population, where all persons originating from a place where all males and females are taller or shorter, makes the determining the relative ratio of Male/Female height harder to assess. But, you could measure in a family, the respective ratio in height adjusted for age and use this ratio and not absolute height as your data. Could add a relative weight variable also.

Comment: @AJKOER Would you say my 2 assumptions are okay just by looking at the summary of the ANCOVA?